# mysql/sql search for first name and last name with one keyword string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following fields: firstname and lastname
keyword is `$keyword`
if someone searches for: John Doe
I want it to be able to return results. 
now it returns results if its john, or if its doe. 
here is the code:

```
$q1 = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
$q=str_replace(" ","%",$q1);
$sql = "select DISTINCT users.*, user_id FROM users WHERE $email_filter 
firstname LIKE '%$q%' OR lastname LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY lastname";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) { echo $results }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: Before you supply $q, replace all spaces with `%`, or supply two parameters; $first_name and $last_name.

Answer (score 0):

You want cases where the first name and the last name match your parameters, not the first name or the last name so it should be firstname LIKE '%$q%' AND lastname LIKE '%$q%'

Keep in mind that since you are using LIKE, if the name is John Doe, Johnnie Doe, John Does, Johnnie Does these will all be returned along with any other records where the first name contains John and the last name contains Doe.

Comment: thats not gonna work if I use AND then it has to check both fields for that $q value. so they BOTH need to have that. it returns no results now

Comment: ahh I missed that you were passing the same value for both fields.  Is there any way to parse it up in to two values?

Answer (score 0):

If the user provides a response like "John Doe" this should trim any extra white space, break the provided names into values and query on them based on your provided code:

```
$q1 = trim(strtolower($_GET["q"]));
$name = explode(" ",$q1);
$fname = $name[0];
$lname = $name[1];
$sql = "select DISTINCT users.*, user_id FROM users WHERE $email_filter 
firstname LIKE '%$fname%' OR lastname LIKE '%$lname%' ORDER BY lastname";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) { echo $results; }
```

hope it helps

Comment: I don't think this would work right in cases where a first name or last name has a space in it - like "Mary Sue Smith".